# Adding elements to top of Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm working on a app which features are below :

1. Loads 10 images from the internet given the urls.
2. On start the 10 urls are in a arraylist that is passed to my baseadapter class. At the top of the list view are 2 buttons.
3. Once that adds a image at the top (Button 2) and one that adds to the bottom (Button 1). I can't seem to get the image to be added to the start of the listview (code under the R.Id.Button2)

**It currently just places an image at the bottom.**

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String dirPath;
MyAdapter Ada;
Button B,B2;
 ListView L;
 ArrayList<String> data= new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> FirstList = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    B= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "newfoldername";

    FirstList.add("url 1");
    FirstList.add("url 2");
    FirstList.add("url 3");
    FirstList.add("url 4");
    FirstList.add("url 5");
    FirstList.add("url 6");
    FirstList.add("url 7");
    FirstList.add("url 8");
    FirstList.add("url 9");
    FirstList.add("url 10);
    L=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    B.setOnClickListener(this);
    B2.setOnClickListener(this);
    data= (ArrayList<String>) FirstList.clone();



     Ada = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,data,dirPath);
    L.setAdapter(Ada);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    switch(v.getId())
    {
       case R.id.button1:
           data.add("url 11");
           Ada.notifyDataSetChanged();

        break;

       case R.id.button2:
           ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
           n.add("url 12");

             n.addAll(data);


            Ada = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,n,dirPath);
            L.setAdapter(Ada);
            Ada.notifyDataSetChanged();


           break;





    }

 }



   }
```

Comment: u can add at specific loc. use add() of 2 arg.

Comment: add column into database and sort via date when you fetch your data from Database.

Answer (score 0):

the method `list.add()` will always add an item at the bottom. In order to add the item to the top of the list, try :

```
1. Create an empty list, and add the new item into the list
2. using addAll method of the new list created, add the first list 
that has all the other elements
3. Pass the new list that is populated to the adapter class, 
or replace the old list with the new list
```

Result:
The item that you wish to add will be at the top now.

Hope the hint helps!

Comment: ArrayList<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
      n.add("url 12");
     
        n.addAll(data);
        
     data.clear();
        data= (ArrayList<String>) n.clone();
        
     
       Ada = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this,data,dirPath);
       L.setAdapter(Ada);
       Ada.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: try logging the values entered in the list n and find out where the mistake is, or may be even remove Ada.notify method.

Comment: or even, using the same arraylist data, and use method arrayList.add(position, value)

Comment: I did log the values in n, It is correct. The values of the url are in the correct order. By I just displays the wrong image

Answer (score 0):

basically, Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille's answer is almost complete, the only change I would make in the stages is:

1. create an empty list and add an object to it.
2. add a bunch of new objects manually or with `addAll`.
3. define the list to stack from bottom with [this XML value](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3astackFromBottom).
4. pass the new list into the adapter.
5. call `Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`